# Binding a Label's text property (in an FXML file) to an IntegerProperty (in a controller)

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, fxml

I've set up a data binding between a Label in an FXML file and an IntegerProperty in the associated controller. The problem is that, while the label gets set to the correct value upon initialization, it is not updating when the property's value changes.

**FXML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
   fx:controller="application.PaneController" minWidth="200">
   <Label id="counterLabel" text="${controller.counter}" />
   <Button translateX="50" text="Subtract 1"
      onAction="#handleStartButtonAction" />
</GridPane>
```

**Controller**

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class PaneController implements Initializable
{
    private IntegerProperty counter;

    public int getCounter()
    {
        return counter.get();
    }

    public void setCounter(int value)
    {
        counter.set(value);
    }

    public PaneController()
    {
        counter = new SimpleIntegerProperty(15);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleStartButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        setCounter(getCounter() - 1);
        System.out.println(getCounter());
    }
}
```

**Expectation**

Each time I push the "Subtract 1" button, the counter will decrement by 1, and the counterLabel will update automatically.

**Reality**

The counter does decrement by 1, but the counterLabel remains stuck at 15 (the initial value).

**Question**

I was under the impression (e.g., from [this forum post](https://forums.oracle.com/message/10476076)) that what I've done should work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to add a JavaFX specific accessor *variableName***Property** to the controller:

```
public IntegerProperty counterProperty() {
    return counter;
}
```

**EDIT: More details.**
The API documentation mentions not so much about this JavaFX's JavaBeans architecture. Just an introduction about it here ([Using JavaFX Properties and Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm)) but again nothing about its necessity.

So lets dig some source code! :)
Straightforwardly, we start to look into [FXMLLoader code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/fxml/src/main/java/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java) first. We notice prefix for binding expression as

```
public static final String BINDING_EXPRESSION_PREFIX = "${";
```

Further at line 279 FXMLLoader determines `if (isBindingExpression(value))` then to create binding, instantiates `BeanAdapter` and gets propertyModel:

```
BeanAdapter targetAdapter = new BeanAdapter(this.value);
ObservableValue<Object> propertyModel = targetAdapter.getPropertyModel(attribute.name);
```

If we look into [BeanAdapter](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/raw-file/17d67b5a5a00/modules/fxml/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/fxml/BeanAdapter.java)`#getPropertyModel()`,

```
public <T> ObservableValue<T> getPropertyModel(String key) {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return (ObservableValue<T>)get(key + BeanAdapter.PROPERTY_SUFFIX);
}
```

it delegates to `BeanAdapter#get()` after appending `String PROPERTY_SUFFIX = "Property";`
In the get() method, simply the getter (either counterProperty or getCounter or isCounter) invoked by reflection, returning the result back. If the getter does not exist null returned back. In other words, if the "counterProperty()" does not exist in JavaBean, null returned back in our case. In this case the binding is not performed due to the statement `if (propertyModel instanceof Property<?>)` in FXMLLoader. As a result, no "counterProperty()" method no bindings.

What happens if the getter is not defined in the bean? Again from the `BeanAdapter#get()` code we can say that if the "getCounter()" cannot be found the null returned back and the caller just ignores it as no-op imo.

Comment: I tried that before, but it didn't work because I also changed my FXML markup to `${controller.counterProperty}`. If I leave it as just `${controller.counter}`, it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: Also, interestingly, it fails if I remove the definitions to `getCounter()` and `setCounter()` (and just work with the `counter` field directly). Does this mean getters/setters on the controller are used by the binding mechanism? (It's unexpected that I would need to provide a getter for the *property* as well as a getter/setter for the *value* of the property.)

Comment: Thanks for that update, Uluk! Definitely helps to understand the system better. I would give you another +1 if I could.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your answers. In my FXML file in intellij  the controller keyword is red showing the error message `Cannot resolve symbol 'controller'`. when i run it - everthing works fine though. seems like an intellij integration failure. Someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: @JuHwon, I am not on intellij. So the only guess is you may forgotten the "fx" prefix, namely it should be "fx:controller".

Comment: Adobe/Apache Flex does it better. I wonder, couldn't we just have an @ Property or @ Binding annotation which cuts down on the boilerplate? But I guess this will do...

Comment: I think my unconscious is not happy with me experimenting with JavaFX: for a moment, I read `BeanAdapter#get()` as `BeanAdapter.regret()`...