# How to map a form to a bean in Java FX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a form made with fxml, it has like 20 fields. (I.e. Person) and I have my controller with the 20 fields (one for every field) o want to know if there is a way to box all these fields in a unique bean like PersonBean. Actually I have to set all the fields to the bean manually in the initialize method.

Something like in the Id of the fxml input put something like "person.name".

Comment: Take a look at [FXForm2 - Automatic form generation and binding to bean properties](http://dooapp.github.io/FXForm2/), or see the [ControlsFX PropertySheet](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/PropertySheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try something like:

```
text="${controller.person.name}"
```

where person is a property of the controller and name is a property of PersonBean.

See:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding
- [Binding a Label's text property (in an FXML file) to an IntegerProperty (in a controller)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822717/binding-a-labels-text-property-in-an-fxml-file-to-an-integerproperty-in-a-co)

You might need to provide JavaFX properties such as

```
ObjectProperty<PersonBean> personProperty();
StringProperty nameProperty();
```

but maybe there is also some support for plain JavaBeans properties.