# Is there a `strings.xml` file in JavaFX?

Tags: java, android, xml, javafx

I come from Android programming (with Android Studio), and I  couldn't avoid asking myself: is there a "`strings.xml`" equivalent in JavaFX? If not, how to implement it?

I'm using **JavaFX** (on Intellij IDEA) and I'm designing my application windows on some `.fxml` files (with SceneBuilder). On some of them there will be showed **big blocks of text**.

```
  <Text lineSpacing = "2.0"
        strokeType = "OUTSIDE"
        strokeWidth = "0.0"
        text = "VERY LONG TEXT THAT WILL COMPROMISE FXML FILE READABILITY"
        wrappingWidth = "220.0" />
```

In the example above I would like to write something like `text = "@string/mymessage"` instead of the long text.

Comment: You're looking for "variable binding", which I believe can be only be done from the Java side

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822717/binding-a-labels-text-property-in-an-fxml-file-to-an-integerproperty-in-a-co

Comment: Use a resource bundle: if you want you can provide a properties file for only one languge. Brief description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution), also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143392/javafx-2-and-internationalization.